# Xamarin add wcf service, I can't run my project in IOS

Tags: c#, ios, wcf, xamarin

An error occurred after compiling on iOS.

- I am using mac OS on virtualbox to open the iOS emulator.
- Xamarin.Forms adds WCF service.
- could not be compiled.

**Code in reference file**

```
 [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    ServiceGolf.CheckLoginResponse ServiceGolf.ServiceGolfSoap.CheckLogin(ServiceGolf.CheckLoginRequest request)
    {
        return base.Channel.CheckLogin(request);
    }
```

**Error Messages**

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'MonoTouch does not support dynamic proxy code generation. Override this method or its caller to return specific client proxy instance'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59PJ3.png)

Pictures show all information https://ibb.co/p4m7z59

Comment: have you read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/web-services/wcf)?  And if possible avoid WCF, it will lead to nothing but pain and anguish.  Use RESTful services instead

Comment: Thank you for your advice.  I will try to understand how to the document.